iPhone screen wake log with timestamps
Imazing to download logs off iPhone
And see screen wake logs
Imaging can get logs off a iPhone
but where is the screen wake logs
So if any one knows where activity logs are on imazing they can show
Or where the data with timestamp

There is iphone screen wake logs in data

Ya wake screen logs is it with a time

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
